# jQuery image sliding right not repeating instantly

Tags: jquery, html, slider, repeat

As you can see.. it will eventually repeat but after a full cycle of black background. I would like find a way to make it so the second the actual image passes, the start of the image is connected right at the end so you see no black while scrolling. Any ideas?

## **HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

## **CSS**

```
/* Give the header a height and a background image */
#header{
    height:150px; 
    background: #000 url(Logo.jpg) repeat-y scroll left top;
    text-align:center;
}
```

## **JS**

```
var scrollSpeed = 50;        // Speed in milliseconds
var step = 1;               // How many pixels to move per step
var current = 0;            // The current pixel row
var imageHeight = 4300;     // Background image height
var headerHeight = 300;     // How tall the header is.

//The pixel row where to start a new loop
var restartPosition = -(imageHeight - headerHeight);

function scrollBg(){

    //Go to next pixel row.
    current -= step;

    //If at the end of the image, then go to the top.
    if (current == restartPosition){
        current = 0;
    }

    //Set the CSS of the header.
    $('#header').css("background-position",current +"px 1");


}

//Calls the scrolling function repeatedly
var init = setInterval("scrollBg()", scrollSpeed);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think is the cause of the problem.

change this

```
var init = setInterval("scrollBg()", scrollSpeed);
```

to

```
var init = setInterval(function(){scrollBg()}, scrollSpeed);
```

Comment: Sadly that didnt work.. I add the change and still does not repeat instantly at the end of the image. You still see a full cycle of black before it restarts.

Comment: @JoelSamson check this http://jsfiddle.net/EbX9y/.  If you open console, you can find the difference.  Anyway update the fiddle so we can figure out the problem.

Comment: Thanks alot! I found the fix. I had to change: `background: #000 url(Logo.jpg) repeat-y scroll left top;` to `background: #000 url(Logo.jpg) repeat-x scroll left top;`

Comment: @JoelSamson Great!! Happy to know you got it fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer was in the **CSS** i had to change the following code:

```
background: #000 url(Logo.jpg) repeat-y scroll left top;
```

To

```
background: #000 url(Logo.jpg) repeat-x scroll left top;
```

Changing repeat-**y** to repeat-**x** allowed it to repeat without a spacing in between since the image is scrolling on the x not the y.

*Example of the solution can be found here:* jsfiddle.net/EbX9y/10